# Alert pop up not showing up second time

Tags: javascript, html, popup, coding-style, alert

I am new to learning javascript.
so ,i made simple html with just header file and linked simple javascript code file to it with this code.
alert pop is displaying once but not second time.

```js
var pounds = prompt("Enter your weight in Pounds");

var kg = 0.456 * pounds;

Alert("Your weight is:" +"kg");
```

Comment: `Alert() != alert()`. Case matters. There should be a nice error message in your developer console. I made your code runnable, run it and the snipplet will show you the error message that is in your developer console.

Comment: Normally, JavaScript is written in camelCase. To differentiate between classes and functions, classes generally start with an uppercase, and functions and other identifiers with lowercase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is simply a typo. [In Javascript, all identifiers are case sensitive](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/Is-JavaScript-a-case-sensitive-language), so `Alert()` is *not* the same thing as `alert()`. ([MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert))

You're looking for `alert()` here:

```js
var pounds = prompt("Enter your weight in Pounds");

var kg = 0.456 * pounds;

alert("Your weight is:" + "kg");
```

Comment: Just a heads up, since this is your first question. On StackOverflow, when you receive an answer that you feel answers your question well, [you can mark it as "accepted"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) in order to designate it as the answer you found the most useful. It gives you a small reputation boost, and rewards the answerer some points too.

Answer (score 1):

`alert` should not be capitolized

```js
var pounds = prompt("Enter your weight in Pounds");

var kg = 0.456 * pounds;

alert(`Your weight is: ${kg}kg`);
```

Answer (score 0):

`alert("Your weight is:"+ kg+"kg");`